Making child div stay inside parent div css
I am trying to make a child div (div inside another) stay inside of the parent and not come out of it. I would like for the options div to stay inside of the header div at all times.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Noah</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #0B0F25;
            font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
            
            color: white;


            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;

        }

        #header {
            background-color: #0B0F25;
            width: 100vw;

            border-bottom: .5px solid black;
            border-top: 1.5px solid black;
            height: 5vw;
            background-color: purple;
            
        }

        #cmdLine {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #cmdTitle {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        #options {
            position: absolute;
            width: 10vw;
            background-color: pink;
        }

        #help {
            padding: 5px;
            display: inline-block;

        }
        
        #action {
            padding: 5px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

    </style>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "header">
        <h3 id = "cmdTitle"> Noah@Noah: ~</h3>

        <div id = "options">
            <h2 id = "action">Actions</h2>
            <h2 id = "help">Help</h2>
        </div>

    </div>
    <p id = "cmdLine">$</p>
</body>

</html>

This displays this:
.
each div has an ID. I have tried setting position: absolute on the header div then once again on the options div but no luck.

Add position:relative to the #header style. Additionally, add top: 0 to the #options style. You can adjust the position of the options element by using top, right, left, bottom and specifying your desired value in front. See below for the updated code
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<head>
  <title>Noah</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <style>
    body {
        background-color: #0B0F25;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;

        color: white;


        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

    }

    #header {
        background-color: #0B0F25;
        width: 100vw;
        position: relative;
        border-bottom: .5px solid black;
        border-top: 1.5px solid black;
        height: 5vw;
        background-color: purple;

    }

    #cmdLine {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #cmdTitle {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    #options {
        position: absolute;
        width: 10vw;
        background-color: pink;
    }

    #help {
        padding: 5px;
        display: inline-block;

    }

    #action {
        padding: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h3 id="cmdTitle"> Noah@Noah: ~</h3>

    <div id="options">
        <h2 id="action">Actions</h2>
        <h2 id="help">Help</h2>
    </div>

  </div>
  <p id="cmdLine">$</p>
</body>

</html>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Noah</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <style>
      body {
        background-color: #0b0f25;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        color: white;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #header {
        width: 100vw;
        border-bottom: 0.5px solid black;
        border-top: 1.5px solid black;
        background-color: purple;
      }

      #cmdLine {
        padding: 10px;
      }

      #cmdTitle {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      #options {
        width: 10%;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
        background-color: pink;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      #help {
        padding: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      #action {
        padding: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <h3 id="cmdTitle">Noah@Noah: ~</h3>

      <div id="options">
        <h2 id="action">Actions</h2>
        <h2 id="help">Help</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p id="cmdLine">$</p>
  </body>
</html>

Try this code. If you have any problem, feel free to reach out to me.

When you set the #options to absolute, it's set relative to the h3, adding  a top property will position it higher.
#options {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            width: 10vw;
            background-color: pink;
        }


Add the position to relative in the #header div, in your previous code. You had the position of "#options div" to absolute but it took the position relative to the html tag considering it as the ancestor. when you add "position:  relative" to div with id "header", it will consider it as the ancestor. Here's a code for you:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Noah</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #0B0F25;
            font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
            color: white;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #header {
            background-color: purple;
            width: 100vw;
            border-bottom: .5px solid black;
            border-top: 1.5px solid black;
            height: 5vw;
            position: relative; /* Making the "#header" div the parent/ancestor of div "#options" */
        }

        #cmdLine {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #cmdTitle {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        #options {
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px; /* Positioning to the right inside the header */
            top: 50%; /*positions the top edge of the element (in this case, the #options div) at 50% of the height of its containing element (the #header div).*/
            transform: translateY(-50%); /* Center vertically */
            background-color: pink;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #help, #action {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 5px;
        }

    </style>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h3 id="cmdTitle"> Noah@Noah: ~</h3>
        <div id="options">
            <h2 id="action">Actions</h2>
            <h2 id="help">Help</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p id="cmdLine">$</p>
</body>

</html>

